# Flex disable draginitiator?

Tags: apache-flex, drag

I'm trying to disable the draginitiator, that's the semi-transparant object when you drag something.
Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT Code

```
<s:List id="dg_ads" top="75" bottom="0" width="100%" borderVisible="false" 
    dragEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true"
    dragComplete="dg_ads_dragCompleteHandler(event)"
    doubleClickEnabled="true" doubleClick="dg_ads_doubleClickHandler(event)"
    contentBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
        <s:layout>
            <s:TileLayout useVirtualLayout="false" clipAndEnableScrolling="false"
                          horizontalGap="5" verticalGap="5" />
        </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom list class that extends spark List and override createDragIndicator() method.This is method is used by the DragManager to create the dragProxy(The image you will see when a drag operation is in progress).

```
override public function createDragIndicator():IFlexDisplayObject
        { 
            var dragIndicator:UIComponent;
            dragIndicator = new UIComponent();
            dragIndicator.width = 0;
            dragIndicator.height = 0;
            return dragIndicator;
        }
```

Use the custom list instead of spark List in your application

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217859/flex-drag-drop-event-is-it-possible-to-access-the-image-being-dragged):

Try:

```
event.dragInitiator.visible = false;
```

or create your own version of the [`DragProxy` class](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/branches/3.4.0/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/managers/dragClasses/DragProxy.as) and remove the portions you don't want.

Comment: this code sets the whole list's visibility to false, I need the opposite.

Comment: @def You could either specify a custom Image as the dragInitiator so that it's displayed instead of the transparent box, or you would have to create your own version of the DragProxy class that I linked to above. The related question I linked to also had some additional tips.